# How do I get the Google/Facebook first name/surname in ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, google-oauth, facebook-oauth

I'm building an application using ASP.NET MVC and Identity and I have Google logins working, but I'd like to display the user's name (from Google/Facebook), so that rather than the website showing as "Hi fred123@gmail.com" it displays as "Hi Fred". I'm aware of how to customise the ApplicationUser, it's just the interaction with the providers I'm not too sure about.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5):

On `ExternalLoginCallback` method you can get all the details.

```
  //code omitted for clarity
  public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

        var identity = AuthenticationManager.GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        var emailClaim = identity.Result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email);
        var lastNameClaim = identity.Result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Surname);
        var givenNameClaim = identity.Result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.GivenName);

        var email = emailClaim.Value;
        var firstName = givenNameClaim.Value;
        var lastname = lastNameClaim.Value;
     }
```

Comment: works for google but not for facebook, any idea how to solve that